# status code : 404 , reponse : {"message":" ... is not a valid BotId/BotAliasId combination."}

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, chatbot, amazon-lex

I deployed the lex bot using https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-a-web-ui-for-your-chatbot/ this method.

I am getting the message:

```
"Sorry, I was unable to process your message. Try again later."
```

when I type some text, and in console when I checked I got status code 404 and response:

```
{"message":" ... is not a valid BotId/BotAliasId combination."}.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My lex bot and lambda function was in Singapore region and i was deploying it in Ireland. I deployed it in singapore and error was gone. But, new error was not able to see the image response card sent from the lambda function :(

Comment: I was able to see the images response by sending a plain text along with image response in messages array from lambda response.  I was using lex v2

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the 'build' button for the bot, and once the bot is successfully built, this error message should disappear. (Select your lex bot -> Select intents -> click on the build button)